# UK comedy book about a man falsely accused of murder while his wife is off with the new neighbours

Tags: identification-request

This should be easy to remember, but I'm having a senior moment.

In the 1980s, potentially early 1990s, I read a very funny book about a man whose wife goes off with the new neighbours on a houseboat and the husband is soon on the hook for killing her. She learns they are swingers, at which point she escapes on a floaty. Meanwhile he's accused of disposing of the body in his college class's meat grinder. Noticing one of the officers having a meat pie, he agrees with them and says he put it in the filling. Eventually everything unwinds and they live happily ever after.

This was a pretty well-known book, at least in the UK. So much so that they turned it into a moderately OK movie, but like so many, the timing just wasn't *on*.

In any event, does anyone recall the title? I'm looking for some summer reading for a friend and thought they'd like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wilt](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/astrofella.wordpress.com/2015/07/30/wilt-tom-sharpe/amp/), by Tom Sharpe

> The police are called and several witnesses come forward to wildly misinterpret what they saw as Wilt throwing a body down the hole and – because his wife has taken an unscheduled break with the Californian couple on a boat in the Broads and is nowhere to be found – the police arrest Wilt on suspicion of murder.

Comment: Huh. This came to my mind too, but as well as not remembering its name, I also never actually read it and thought it didn't fit except in broad strokes. +1.

Comment: Well the OP's rendering isn't exact... no-one ever said Wilt and Eva lived happily ever after....

Comment: And it seems I'm remembering one scene from the movie version, not the book.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I can’t remember the book too well, but I think Eva escapes the houseboat naked on a lilo while Wilt has adventures trying to dispose of an inflated sex doll. I imagine scope for a lot of cinematic visuals... and I definitely remember the meat pie bit from either that book or a sequel.